# verb "ausmachen" goes to the end

Tags: english-to-german

Why does the verb go to the end?

> In der Schule bitte die Handys ausmachen!

Answer (score 6):

In English, you would use the imperative form of the verb with "please":

> Please turn off cell phones at school.

This imperative form also exists in German, which would look like this:

> Bitte macht in der Schule die Handys aus!

However, in German, often the infinitive form of the verb is used instead to express short asks, requests or orders, especially when they are directed at a general public instead of certain persons. So in that case, we don't even make it a full sentence, but just the verb in its infinitive form.

> Bitte warten! *(please wait)*

In German, other than in English, with infinitives, all the objects always stand before the verb in infinitive:

> *to step on the grass* => das Gras betreten
> *to turn off the cell phone* => das Handy ausmachen

> She asked the pupils to switch off the phones => Sie bat die Schüler, die Handys auszuschalten.

So that's why it is:

> Bitte das Gras nicht betreten
> Einfahrt freihalten
> Bitte an der Theke zahlen
> In der Schule bitte die Handys ausmachen

Comment: so no need to save position 2 as verb?

Comment: @ArazTäbris no need, because it isn't a full sentence, just a verb with objects.

Answer (score 3):

In German, *all verbs go to the end by default*, in reverse order than in English. There doesn't have to be a reason why a verb is at the end. Rather, there has to be a reason why a verb is **not** at the end.

For example, in main clauses, the very last word order rule applied is the V2 rule. You take the conjugated verb from the very end, break loose its prefixes if it has any, and move that conjugated stem to second position, so it can separate the topic of the main clause from its remainder. That's the function of the V2 verb.

In your example, the reason why *ausmachen* stays at the end is that this sentence has an ellipsis. *Ausmachen* isn't a conjugated verb in this sentence! It's an infinitive. The complete sentence is

> (Ihr sollt) in der Schule bitte die Handys ausmachen!

It's not really a command but rather a reminder phrased as a modal expression. That's why there's no imperative mood involved.

This sort of ellipsis is very common on signage but also in speech. As that *du sollst*, *ihr sollt*, or *Sie sollen* is very affirmative and harsh. If you don't omit it, that person addressed will feel snubbed.